# Limit the scope of tag search in Finder on Mavericks

Tags: macos, finder, finder-tag

I have a fairly extensive file system with a large collection of images and a duplicate disc of those images and, additionally, some folders with images that are in process of some workflow.

I have tagged some of these files. If I click a tag in the Finder's sidebar, ALL the files with that tag are shown throughout the file system.

Is there a way to limit the search by tag to a certain folder (and it's contained folders) in the Finder?

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. **Finder -> Preferences -> Advanced** does not limit the scope when tags are used.
2. If click a tag and then try and add limiting information in the search box, the tag is lost.
3. If I click to the parent folder, then type `tag:Red` in the search folder, the files with that specific tag are not shown

I can use `mdfind` at the command line, but that does not give a Finder window with the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get there from the tag view accessed from the sidebar, but if you navigate to the directory you want to search, and type the tag you're looking for, it will find files in that directory.

[image: directory to search, with enclosed files]
[image: resulting search]